# How to read the value including ampersand in this case

Tags: jquery

I have got a sample url as shown below

```
var sampleurl = 'index.html?UUID=testuuid&tablenum=glow&glory&cust_id=53&minimum_order=0';
```

The tablenum has got value as **'glow&glory'**

But when i am reading this  , i am only getting value as glow (the value after ampersand is lost)

Could you please let me know how to get the value 'glow&glory'

This is my code

```
var sampleurl = 'index.html?UUID=23232311222&tablenum=table&seat&cust_id=53&minimum_order=0';

$(document).ready(function(){

 var tablenumval = getParameterByName('tablenum');

 alert(tablenumval);

});


function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(sampleurl);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Ag73M/16/

Answer (score 2):

The code is correct, because the value of `tablenum` is only `glow`.

Parameters in an url are separated using the `&` so if you want to have `&` as part of your value you need to escape it using `%26`, so it has to be `tablenum=glow%26glory`

In your url `glory` would be a new parameter with an empty/not set value.

Always use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)  to escape the values in your url, if you don't use JavaScript to compose your url then you need to look for the equivalent function for the language in which you create the url.

Comment: To put in another way for the OP: if you *wanted* to express the key/value pair `tablenum=glow` followed by the key `glory` with no value, how would you do it? You'd do `tablenum=glow&glory`, which is what the URL currently says.

Comment: I am okay to write a seperate function for achieving this , i mean getParameterByNamefortablename()

Comment: @PreethiJain you should correct the source of your problem and fix the url. Creating a workaround in the code is always a bad idea, because you will have problems with maintaining your code and it might introduce further problems in future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sampleurl = 'index.html?UUID=testuuid&tablenum=' + encodeURIComponent('glow&glory') + '&cust_id=53&minimum_order=0';
```